# Winrt Syncfusion TileView control selectionChanged event not firing

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, syncfusion

I am working on a win8 app using Syncfusion controls. I used a TileView control in a page with 4 hardcoded items in xaml.
I want to capture a event to find out which item is in maximized state or clicked.
I tried selectionchanged event of TileView but that's not firing even tap event of TileViewItem also not firing.
Is there any way?
I tried to use same thing with the sample code. same result.

I found something after **editing template**
There is no property like IsItemClickEnabled.

Comment: Does TileView have some sort of `ItemClick` event? Check for an `IsItemClickEnabled` property as well. If you have `ItemClickEnabled`, generally it won't fire the `SelectionChanged` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked Syncfusion TileView Control in latest version 11.2.0.64, SelectionChanged event is firing in TileView when we select item and maximized item was identified through MaximizedItem property of TileView.

Sample :

http://www.syncfusion.com/uploads/user/directTrac/General/TileView_StackOverflow-347277746.zip